# Allowing cursor interaction on two elements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: Updated to use a code snippet, thanks for the advice [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)!

I've seen questions similar to this asked and answered, but I think I have a wrinkle in my case that changes things. I've been messing with the [Pts.js library](https://ptsjs.org/), and am trying to figure out how to use it in the background of a page while allowing it to interact with the user's cursor (or pointer).

I've included a snippet that I hopegets the idea across. Essentially what I'd like to accomplish is allow the mouse to interact with texts and links normally in one element, but allow the Pts element to continue to track the mouse movements "beneath" that. Thanks for your attention!

```js
(function() {
let run = Pts.quickStart("#pts", "#edf7fa");

run((time, ftime) => {
  form.fillOnly("blue").circle(Circle.fromCenter(space.pointer, 5));
});
})();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#pts {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pts/0.8.11/pts.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Hey! Thanks for checking this out. I'd really love to have this message here, but I'd also like for the animation to track the mouse movements while the mouse is here too. I'd use "pointer-events: 'none'", but I'd also like to have <a href="nowhere">links that are still clickable in this element</a>.
      What are your thoughts?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="pts" />
</div>
```

Comment: Probably not related, but the ending tag of `div` element is mandatory, it's not a self-closing element.

Comment: @Teemu It would be fine if he specified xhtml where that's valid, or is a common folly for folks who use things more often like xml, xaml, etc. (AKA, it took me awhile to break that habit too after transitioning back to html from writing loads of xaml every day after years) :D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oops, thanks for that! I’ll get that up in just a bit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks again for the pointer, just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a a lot about the library you are using but you can easily do this without:

```js
document.documentElement.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--x',e.clientX +'px ');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--y',e.clientY +'px ');
}
```

```css
html {
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at var(--x,0) var(--y,0),blue 5px,transparent 6px),
    #edf7fa;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pts/0.8.11/pts.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Hey! Thanks for checking this out. I'd really love to have this message here, but I'd also like for the animation to track the mouse movements while the mouse is here too. I'd use "pointer-events: 'none'", but I'd also like to have <a href="nowhere">links that are still clickable in this element</a>.
      What are your thoughts?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: kudos for css variables

Comment: Hi Temani, thanks for the response! What I'm trying to accomplish in the long term is to have things more similar to [the examples on the library's site](https://ptsjs.org/demo/?name=circle.intersectCircle2D). I suppose though that I could probably use `document.documentElement.onmousemove` to simply store the `clientX` and `clientY` in JavaScript variables and then use those as I need to. Now I'm going to ask a kind of remedial JavaScript question, but how would I go about storing those values to then be used later?

Comment: You can simply consider a global variable in your JS file `var x,y;` and then later inside the mousemove you do `x = e.clientX` .. then you use the `x` anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for the help [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)! Using the `.onmousemove` function and storing the `clientX` and `clientY` is absolutely the trick.

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

document.documentElement.onmousemove = function(e) {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
}

function draw() {
  let run = Pts.quickStart("#pts", "#edf7fa");
  
  run((time, ftime) => {
    form.fillOnly("blue").circle(Circle.fromCenter(new Pt([x,y]), 5));
  });
}

draw();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#pts {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pts/0.8.11/pts.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Hey! Thanks for checking this out. I'd really love to have this message here, but I'd also like for the animation to track the mouse movements while the mouse is here too. I'd use "pointer-events: 'none'", but I'd also like to have <a href="nowhere">links that are still clickable in this element</a>.
      What are your thoughts?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="pts" />
</div>
```